# cygwin + java = unkillable java process, then BSOD (Blue Screen Of Death)

Tags: java, maven, cygwin, bsod

Crossing my fingers hoping that someone else has had and solved this problem..

I run cygwin on my office Windows XP Pro machine, and run maven on my java projects.

In about 1 out of every 30/40 mvn commands, the java command will hang with no output on the screen, and take up my entire CPU usage (I've got 2 CPUs).  Nothing works to kill it, not ctrl-C, task manager, killpid, kill -9, nothing that I've tried.  If I try to shutdown, windows hangs and I need to manually power down the machine.  If I continue working then a while later another instance hangs so now I'll have both CPU's pegged, and a few seconds later, a Blue Screen of Death.

I've tried using javaw, no help.

Any other ideas?

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 1):

Not an actual answer to your problem, but make sure you're running [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) in the background.

First, this will reveal which process is the most hungry for CPU, if java or bash.exe.

Second, its kill command is much more reliable than a Ctrl-C. I've seen processes resist a Ctrl-C signal, but I have yet to see a process stand against a kill command from ProcessExplorer.

Comment: `kill -9` is the most powerful. Use wisely.

Comment: Thanks Kitsune, actually I tried kill -9 too (just added that to my desc. above)

Comment: Thanks Leonel - I didn't know about that tool, very useful!  Unfortunately it still won't kill the process.. little bugger still sits there eating CPU.